# Backup MYSQL remote server database via ssh using mysqldump

Tags: java, mysql, ssh, remote-server

I want to backup a mysql database which is a remote server monitoring over ssh. So, I wrote a code using mysqldump and java to achieve this task. My remote server details are mentioned below.

Connection Method: Standard TCP/IP over SSH
 
SSH Hostname: 172.10.2.14
 
SSH Username: remoteuser
 
SSH Password: remotepwd
 
MYSQL Hostname: 127.0.0.1 (localhost)
 
MYSQL Server Port: 3306
 
Username: root
 
Password: rootpwd
 
DB: db_stores

But when I tried to run the program, it takes quite a long time and get stuck.

```
     String backup_path=backup_path_in;
     String mysql_path=mysql_path_in;
     Process p = null;
    try {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        p = runtime.exec("ssh remoteuser@172.10.2.14 mysql -uremoteuser -premotepwd db_stores | " + 
                mysql_path + "/mysqldump -h127.0.0.1 -uroot -prootpwd --add-drop-database -B db_stores -r " + backup_path + "/"+ cur_date +"-stores.sql");

        int processComplete = p.waitFor();

        if (processComplete == 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Backup created successfully!!!");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Something went wrong!!!");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Any help with this would be great.

Comment: Maybe it takes a long time because you have a lot of data. is it producing output? Is producing a dump on the server and downloading that later with `scp` an option?

Comment: I've tried backup manually using mysql workbench and it worked within 5 mins. But when I run the code, it stuck.

Comment: What code are you running that gets stuck? Not sure how Java factors into this, but if you could show us that would help a lot.

Comment: I'm really sorry @tadman, the code snippet which I include, is not uploaded properly. Now you can view it.

Comment: First thing to test is if that command runs properly outside of Java or not. You need to find out if the problem is your Java wrapper or `mysqldump` itself. Another thing to try is instead of calling `mysqldump` on the remote machine, try using it locally over an SSH tunnel. It's possible that SSH is timing out as well, so consider that. Inactivity on a connection may cause it or your upstream router/firewall to kill the connection.

Comment: For ssh you could use `-nN -L localsocketpath.sock:/var/lib/mysql.sock` and run `mysqldump -S localsocketpath.sock ...` locally.  with `remoteuser@localhost` mysql account with unix socket authentication and the right grants you wouldn't even need to expose the mysql password in the code or server processes.